# Jquery click event not firing on first click and behaves like double click after

Tags: javascript, angular

Jquery click event not firing on first click and behaves like double click after. This is my code. I would love some help. Thanks

```js
faqBodyLoader(id) {
  $("#faqTitle" + id).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#faqBody" + id).toggleClass("hide");
    $("div[id^=faqBody]").removeClass("show");
  });
}
```

```html
<span *ngFor="let data of _table" id="faqList">
  <div class="faq-title d-flex align-items-center" id="faqTitle{{data.faq_id}}"(click)="faqBodyLoader(data.faq_id)">
    {{data.faq_question}}
  </div>
  <div class="faq-body hide" id="faqBody{{data.faq_id}}">
    <span innerHTML="{{data.faq_answer}}"></span>
  </div>
</span>
```

Comment: You already have a _click_ event on the `id="faqTitle{{data.faq_id}}"` element before you define the next event. Every time you click that element, you're defining a new event handler and running all of those attached. Odd's are if you clicked it again, it would be the equivalent of a triple click, then a quadruple click, etc...

Comment: Agree with @War10ck.  You are putting an Angular click event listener on it with (click) and then within that handler function, you are adding another click event listener with jQuery.  Get rid of the jQuery.click(), you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a click event on the id="faqTitle{{data.faq_id}}" element before you define the next event. Every time you click that element, you're defining a new event handler and running all of those attached. Odd's are if you clicked it again, it would be the equivalent of a triple click, then a quadruple click, etc...

Originally posted by War10ck